# Sobipro - stop url rewrite on search results page

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, sobipro

In Sobipro the search results page url always rewrites to www.yourdomain.com/yourCategory/search/results how can I prevent this from happening?

I am using urls to the search function like the example below but the search result page always rewrites to www.yourdomain.com/yourCategory/search/results and google cannot index this.

http://demo.sobi-pro.eu/index.php?option=com_sobipro&task=search.search&sp_search_for=magna&field_city=Duckburg&sid=1&Itemid=46

Is there a way to prevent this rewrite from happening and just leave the link above in the url?